# About a proposition of Willem's book

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $\Omega$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^N$ and let $2<p<\infty$.
The functionals

$\Psi(u)= \int_{\Omega} |u|^p , \chi (u)= \int_{\Omega} |u^+|^p$

are of class $C^2(L^p(\Omega), \mathbb{R}^N)$ and

$
(\Psi ' (u), h)=p \int_{\Omega} |u|^{p-2} uh
$

$
(\chi ' (u), h)= p \int_{\Omega} (u^+)^{p-1}h
$

In the proof of this proposition, when I show that

$
(\Psi ' (u), h)=p \int_{\Omega} |u|^{p-2} uh
$

is valid, I have to calculate:

$
(\Psi ' (u), h)= \lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{1}{t} [\Psi(u+th)-\Psi(u)]
$

That is my problem. How do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

$$
\Psi(u+t\,h)-\Psi(u)=\int_\Omega(|u+t\,h|^p- u|^p).
$$
By the mean value theorem
$$
|u+t\,h|^p- u|^p=p\,(t\,h)\,|(u+t\,\xi)|^{p-2}\,(u+t\,\xi)
$$
where $\xi$ is between $0$ and $h$. Thus
$$
\frac{1}{t}(\Psi(u+t\,h)-\Psi(u))=p\int_\Omega h\,|(u+t\,\xi)|^{p-2}\,(u+t\,\xi).
$$
We have $|(u+t\,\xi)|\le(|u|+|h|)$ if say, $|t|\le1$. Since $u,h\in L^P$, $|u|^{p-1},|h|^{p-1}\in L^q$ and $h\,|(u+t\,\xi)|^{p-1}\in L^1$. By the dominated convergence theorem
$$
\lim_{t\to0}\frac{1}{t}(\Psi(u+t\,h)-\Psi(u))=p\int_\Omega h\,|u|^{p-2}\,u.
$$